# Guitar questions that were migrated shouldn't be closed

Tags: discussion, scope

They were migrated for a reason: they were open, valid questions on guitars.se.com -- closing them because they got folded in to here is not the right approach IMO. Re-tagging them is a better strategy. Example [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/powering-5-high-current-draw-effects-pedals) -- which is completely relevant to musicians playing electric guitar. That closure threatens all questions related to effects and amplifiers as being off topic when really they are not.

Discuss.

Comment: Chat discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1057207#1057207

Comment: Read it, good discussion--I still stand by my convictions though. The key point I'd like to make? There's absolutely nothing wrong with folks who have cross cutting skill sets applying one focus to another. I feel like that brings much more worth to the community than incredibly narrow discussions by pundits. It's most certainly true that optics belong in a discussion about photography--so why isn't it equally valid to argue that electro-magnetics belong in a discussion related to a guitar pickup? Besides, what's wrong with *learning* something? Isn't that an undeclared founding pillar of SE?

Comment: @Jduv I don't disagree, I think it's invaluable to have answers informed by broader knowledge. I just take issue with questions that are tangentially related to music. The presence of other considerations is not a problem, it's the lack of musical considerations. There were none at all in the current-draw question, as I see it.

Comment: Jduv explained that there are pedal-specific considerations for that question, I withdraw my complaint.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen some closings that I consider valid--such as a couple of shopping questions, but I think that the moderators have become a little ambitious towards closing some guitars.SE questions in an attempt to "avoid the problems on guitars.SE" (direct quote). First off, I'm not really sure what that means, so an elaboration on that would be nice--but in particular if we are to enforce the driving logic behind closing questions like the one linked then all questions related to the specifics of some gear (guitar electronics, amp design, effects design, pedalboard design, ad nauseum) should be closed as well. I could argue that circuit design on a Stratocaster is electrical engineering, and consequently belongs on physics.SE, etcetera. The distinction between subject matter inside a broader topic is best handled by tags, not closings. It just so happens that circuit design and a good bit of eMag are very heavily utilized subject matter when designing and describing amplifiers, electric guitars, and guitar effects. It's a cross cutting aspect that in my opinion very much belongs here--every bit as much as questions related to repair, general maintenance, and technique.

Comment: I'm all for discussing the scope of the site.  But the questions imported from Guitars don't automatically determine the scope.  Might I suggest creating a Meta topic about whether the electronics-related questions you mention should be on-topic?

Comment: I don't disagree, but nevertheless those questions should be considered and perhaps the scope widened to accommodate another composite topic. Just because guitars didn't exist when music.SE was penned does that mean that it should be forced into the music.SE mold without some of it's concerns being addressed fairly. I'm not sure if anyone really knows the protocol for a merge like this, and I think what you suggest is a good idea so I'll do that when I get a few free cycles.

Comment: The only real problem guitars.se had was low foot fall - music.se would have exactly the same problem without the merger - which is why im guessing they merged it so soon and to minimise user loss.  The reason for the closure was very well illustrated on the meta before the merge.  At no point were the questions on guitars a factor in the closure.

Comment: Actually one of the arguments for merging in Guitars was that the questions/answers on Guitars were very high quality, so it would be a shame that the contents and users should be lost by just closing the site.